# Pygame Sprite can jump but can't walk

Tags: python, collision-detection, sprite

I've been working through [this online tutorial](http://pyvideo.org/video/1718/introduction-to-pygame) on Pygame (Python Version 3.3.1), and have come to a point where my sprite can jump, but can walk only a few pixels in either direction.  I'd really like to move forward with this code as I like how it is structured (not a lot of code in the Main method).  Can anyone spot what might be causing my sprite to get stuck?

```
import pygame

# Define some colors
black    = (   0,   0,   0)
white    = ( 255, 255, 255)
green    = (   0, 255,   0)
red      = ( 255,   0,   0)

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, *groups):
        super(Player, self).__init__(groups)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('Images\player1.png')
        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect((50, 650), self.image.get_size())
        self.resting = False
        self.dy = 0 #dy represents change in y velocity

    def update(self, dt, game):
        last = self.rect.copy()
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.x -= 300 * dt
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.x += 300 * dt
        #if key[pygame.K_UP]:
        #    self.rect.y -= 300 * dt
        #if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        #    self.rect.y += 300 * dt

        if self.resting and key[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            self.dy = -500 #If space bar is pressed, increase velocity.
        self.dy = min(400, self.dy + 40) #Speed capped at 400. Gravity set at 40.
        self.rect.y += self.dy * dt

        new = self.rect
        self.resting = False
        for cell in pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, game.walls, False):
            #self.rect = last
            cell = cell.rect
            if last.right <= cell.left and new.right > cell.left:
                new.right = cell.left               
            if last.left >= cell.right and new.left < cell.right:
                new.left = cell.right
            if last.bottom <= cell.top and new.bottom > cell.top:
                #if you hit something while jumping, stop.
                self.resting = True
                new.bottom = cell.top
                self.dy = 0
            if last.top >= cell.bottom and new.top < cell.bottom:
                new.top = cell.bottom
                self.dy = 0 #If you hit the floor while jumping, stop


class Game(object):
    def main(self, screen):
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        dt = clock.tick(30)
        #image = pygame.image.load('Images\player1.gif')
        background = pygame.image.load('Images\_rec_bg.png')
        sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.player = Player(sprites)
        self.walls = pygame.sprite.Group()
        block = pygame.image.load('Images\dia_tile.png')
        for x in range(0, 800, 20):
            for y in range(0, 800, 20):
                if x in (0, 800-20) or y in (0, 800-20):
                    wall = pygame.sprite.Sprite(self.walls)
                    wall.image = block
                    wall.rect = pygame.rect.Rect((x, y), block.get_size())
        sprites.add(self.walls)

        running = True
        while running:
            clock.tick(30) #run no more than 30 time per second
            dt - clock.tick(30)
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT or \
                    (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE):
                        running = False


            #sprites.update()
            #sprites.update(dt / 1000.)
            #screen.fill(black)
            sprites.update(dt / 1000., self)
            #screen.blit(image, (320, 240)) #Transfer to video RAM
            screen.blit(background, (0,0))
            sprites.draw(screen)
            pygame.display.flip() #Dispaly to Screen

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))
    Game().main(screen)
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure but it looks like you're only letting the player move from side to side if the player is in the air (jumping)

If i'm right you need to enable youre player to move side to side even when `self.resting = True`

what happens if you do something like this:

```
if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    self.rect.x -= 75
if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
    self.rect.x += 75
```

the thing about that is the player will move from side to sdie but when you jump and press right or left the player will fly all over instead of going into a steady jump and fall

so you need to figure out how to include the `*dt` to regulate the players movement in air but at the same time have the player be able to move while on the ground to

try having two sets of if statments:

```
if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    self.rect.x -= 300 * dt
if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
    self.rect.x += 300 *dt

if key[pygame.K_LEFT]and self.resting:
    self.rect.x -= 50 
if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]and self.resting:
    self.rect.x += 50
```

the first one is for in the air the second is for when the player is on the ground

try that and tell me if it works

i tried it on my computer and it worked but i probably used differnt art that could also be the problem becuase it might be blitting behind something so check everything

Good Luck!!

Comment: I tried your suggestion above, but I get the same result.  I'd add more detail, but I can't get the mark-up on this comment to format my text properly (feel like such a noob).  This does suggest my images may be part of the problem.  I've rewritten the code completely using a different approach and can get my sprite to walk and jump with no problems.  But I will revisit this a bit later.

Comment: Yeah I tweaked the art on mine and it worked but when I changed the art to something different it didn't and since I don't have you're art it's hard sorry I couldn't help you